# Changing symfony assetic directory

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm working on a legacy application that we are slowly migrating to Symfony.
Currently Symfony2.6 (due to PHP version), but soon Symfony3.1.

The legacy application already uses the directories `/css/`, `/js/` in the main root for managing css+js.

The problem is that Assetic will also dump it's files there after compiling css+js files from bundles. But those files are generated and should not end up in git, while the legacy files should be managed by git.

In time the legacy files will disappear completely, and everything will be handled by Assetic, but for now I have to live with both working side-by-side.

I want to reconfigure Assetic to use a different directory when generating the css+js files. It should also adjust the url's used on the webpages accordingly.
Preferably by adding an additional prefix-directory.

So far I've found 2 things that might work:

1: use the `write_to` configuration of the assetic-bundle. However, this appears only to influence the assetic:dump command, and should not be used for changing the output dir (according to comments). This does not change the url used to retrieve the files by the browser.

2: use the `output` parameter for each and every `%javascripts%` and `%stylesheets%` tag in my templates. Although this does appear to control where the file goes, I find it illogical I need to do this on every tag. I should be able to configure this system-wide.

How can I adjust my Symfony and/or Assetic configuration to change the directory and web-dir used for generated css+js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `write to` for output dir and define a base path in your assets, under the framework configuration

```
assetic:
 write_to: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/foo"

framework:
   assets:
     base_path: "foo"
```

there are a new assets components since 2.7 [more info here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component)

and you can call

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeBundle/Resources/public/js/bar.js' output="js/bar.js" %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" defer></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

ps: since symfony 2.8 assetic is not include in the Symfony Standard Edition. you can check for a alternative like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for handle your assets management more easily

Comment: The `write_to` works in symfony2.6, but the `framework.assets.base_path` does not seem to exist in that version. I tried `framework.templating.assets_base_urls.[ssl|http]` (2 keys), but I think they are only used for assets, not css/js.

Comment: When I add the `output` parameter, it will put the file in the directory specified by `write_to`, but this does only affect the filename requested, the url passed in the style-tag is still wrong (and whatever is in `base_path` is not applied)

Comment: Updated application to use the `output` parameter in *all* javascript and stylesheet calls in twig. After upgrading to Symfony2.8 or Symfony3.1 we will revise this to use a more solid and permanent solution.

Comment: Symfony2.6: `framework` > `templating` > `assets_base_urls: "foo"`